# How do I display images from Google Earth by giving co-ordinates using Python?

Tags: python, google-earth

Any ideas on how can I display images from Google Earth by giving co-ordinates using Python. The images should be Satellite Images. I've trying many things from the past month and I am not getting the idea of it.
Help will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: use google earth engine or google maps API

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked google's api ? Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api-guiattard)
In this doc it says :
We can easily get information about our region/point of interest using the following methods (to get more information about available methods and required arguments, please visit the API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs))
i have used google's api for youtube and drive at past so this documents are quite well, would be helpful for you to start understanding the process.